# Specializing function template for templated derived class

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, template-specialization

I essentially have a mock version of `std::integral_constant` that includes a variable and I want to specialize a function template for these classes derived from `Base<T>`, like this:

```
template<class T> struct Base{
  typedef T type;
  T t;
};

template<class T> struct A : Base<T>{
  static constexpr T value = 1;
};
template<class T> struct B : Base<T>{
  static constexpr T value = 2;
};

struct Unrelated{};

// etc.

template<class T> void foo(T t){
  //I would like to specialize foo for A and B and have a version for other types
}


int main(){
  foo(A<float>());//do something special based on value fields of A and B
  foo(B<float>());
  foo(Unrelated()); //do some default behavior
}
```

Here are the main issues:

- I cannot include `value` as a template as I am expecting `T = double`, `float`, or some other non-integral types (otherwise I'd just extend `std::integral_constant`)
- I can't cleanly use `std::is_base` as I would have to do `std::is_base<Base<T::type>,T>`
- Doing `foo(Base<T>&)` wouldn't allow me to see `value` and I don't want to have to resort to a virtual `value()` function (or reflection).
- And obviously I would like to avoid specializing foo for every derived class.

I think the answer lies in using `is_base` but I haven't been able to get it to work no matter how I tried to use it. Is there a much simpler way I am missing?

Comment: Of course, you have a typo or two.  `template<class T> struct A : Base{` should be `template<class T> struct A : Base <T>{`.  Is that your whole problem?

Comment: +1 for clearly expressing first *what* you're trying to do, followed by *how* you're trying to do it, and finally asking *how* you should do what you're trying to do.

Comment: Also, read [this](http://www.gotw.ca/publications/mill17.htm)

Comment: I was sure I had caught that before I pasted it, thanks! But I'm pretty sure I need to specialize as I do not wish to overload for every subtype of Base nor can I overload with Base<T>&.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should work:

```
template<typename,typename = void>
struct IsBase
  : std::false_type {};

template<typename T>
struct IsBase<T, typename std::enable_if<
                   std::is_base_of<Base<typename T::type>,T>::value
                 >::type>
  : std::true_type {};

template<class T>
typename std::enable_if<IsBase<T>::value>::type foo(T t){
    // use T::value
}

template<class T>
typename std::enable_if<!IsBase<T>::value>::type foo(T t){
    // general case
}
```

[**Live example**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4840e91453b5ab10)

Comment: Will not work if I do `foo<Unrelated>()` (for me on g++4.6 at least) even though it doesn't have the issue of failing at `typename T::type.` Like I said, I did virtually the same thing but haven't been able to get it to fully work as I'd like.

Comment: @user783920 `foo<Unrelated>()` does not provide a parameter, but `foo` (as you defined it) requires a parameter `t`. I don't think I can help if you don't provide a correct description of your problem.

Comment: I had removed the template but now it works. I guess I forgot to save or something, sorry.